# Windows Service Unable to get correct System Culture

Tags: c#, .net, cultureinfo, currentculture

From Control Panel, I set my Region and Language setting to French (France)

When I am running my application as console application,

`Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture` returns French

But when I'm running it as windows service, it returns invariant culture or English (US)

Is there a way to fix that?

Comment: Does this question help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20872028/thread-currentthread-currentculture-not-working-in-a-thread-inside-a-threadpool

Comment: Have you tried rebooting the machine after changing the region and language settings?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The service is probably running as a user that has it's own culture.

Why not set the culture when you start your service

```
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("fr-FR");
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo("fr-FR");
```

Also from [Default Culture in a Windows Service](http://discuss.joelonsoftware.com/default.asp?dotnet.12.480326.2)

```
If your Windows Service is running under the SYSTEM account or other account without a 
profile it will use the settings defined under the 
"HKEY_USERS/.DEFAULT/Control Panel/International" registry key.  

You can change these values from "Control Panel / Regional and Language Options / Advanced" 
by checking the checkbox "Apply all settings to the current user account and to the default 
user profile".
```

I normally use the former technique as I only need to change it for a specific service rather than for the whole OS.

Comment: Thank you for posting the solution. It helps me a lot!

Answer (score 0):

`.NET 4.5` added `CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentCulture` and `CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentUICulture` i suggest setting it as early as possible and it should solve your issue.
This will change the current threads culture and all threads that are created.