# C# Windows Service not using Regional Settings info

Tags: c#, windows-services, cultureinfo

I have a .exe file which will generate date in `MM/DD/YY` if I set `short date` format in Regional Settings as `DD/MM/YY`. So when I execute the .exe manually, I get correct output.

But when I use C# Windows Service ( running as Local System), the .exe gives a different format. It means, the C# Windows Service does not read Regional Settings.
I am running on Windows XP and C# 2.0

Comment: Can you provide the system details please. Running as Local system you need to change the registry to achieve correct data format

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Windows Service Unable to get correct System Culture](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26474132/windows-service-unable-to-get-correct-system-culture)

Comment: @mjwills If I set culture info, should I set after myThread.Start() or before ?

Comment: @Rauf As early as possible.